Flexible connection for two iron pipes carrying hot water
As part of a hydronic heating system, I have two sections of black iron pipe, about 2 feet apart, carrying 190F water at 15-20 PSI. Perfectly aligning them to fit a length of pipe between them is proving quite difficult, and would be a challenge I would need to repeat if I ever make changes later.
I would like to connect them with something flexible, of variable length, and not oxygen permeable. My first thought is rubber hose and hose clamps, similar to a car's radiator hoses.
What can I use?

Will it be accessible after(not in cement/something)?

I have no personal experience and minimal enough knowledge that I do not feel comfortable writing an answer. But the TL;DR answer is PEX.

@crip659 Yes, fully accessible.

I would second PEX also.  Choosing the right adapters will take a few extra seconds.  A plumbing shop should be easier than a big box store.

PEX-A in a heating system is typically rated for 200F at 80 PSI. Look for the specific rating printed right on whatever you buy.
